# How can I add a reference in monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

I need to work with Json in mono and I'm using the IDE monodevelop.

How can I add as a reference json.net in monodevelop ?

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_A_Simple_Solution (look for ***`Referencing our Library`***)

Answer (score 19):

In your project there should be a folder called `References`. Right click it and choose `edit references`. Then check the box next to the package you want to add

Answer (score 1):

For monodevelop 4.012 try look in the Solution->Packages->Edit Packages
and look for the library you need.