# How to use JSON Web Token (JWT) in Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication by use of JSON Web Tokens (JWT) in Unity 3D. I searched a lot in google and GitHub and found nothing useful. There is a .NET library in GitHub but i don't know how to use it.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet

I'm new to unity and any help with this would be great.

Comment: Hi, you cane create a HttpRequest and set it headrs for JWT authentication.

Comment: Can you explain it more? as i said i'm new to unity.

Comment: I dont know anything about unity, but I am sure in almost every framework, there are some api to connect to network. You can read this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Connect.html doc. or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951489/unity-get-post-wrapper

Comment: I know how to connect to network and this is not my problem. I just want to Encode and Decode JSON with JWT in unity.

Comment: I saw this article that explains encode and decode. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/890684/Authentication-Using-JSON-Web-Token

Comment: Yes i saw it too. it uses a .Net lib for that and i don't know how to import it in unity.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can easily import that lib as a reference or use Nuget to find the lib.

Comment: No i don't use Visual Studio. I use MonoDevelop - Unity.

Comment: Read this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438122/how-can-i-add-a-reference-in-monodevelop

Answer (score 4):

Here is  one way to decode a JSON web token with C# in Unity

```
var parts = token.Split('.');
if (parts.Length > 2)
{
    var decode = parts[1];
    var padLength = 4 - decode.Length % 4;
    if (padLength < 4)
    {
        decode += new string('=', padLength);
    }
    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(decode);
    var userInfo = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: You should have at least stated that your code is a security vulnerability. You left the signature unverified.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for delay,

I found this: [Jwt.Net](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt)

It actually supports the proper .NET version you need for unity3d which is 3.5 Just try to find DLLs, then put them in your unity project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with unity because that is for `.Net 3.5`.
(https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt)

Unity is still using `.Net 2.0 @ version 5.2`